How can I run multiple instances of a Windows Form app in Visual Studio 2022
I have a solution with two projects, a windows form app to act as the client and a console app to act as the server. Currently, the client is set predefined values on a button click and these values are then sent to the server - currently the id of each client is a randomly generated int.
I need to run multiple instances of the client to have numerous instances of them connect to the server. How can I do this
I have tried the comments suggestions but when i run multiple instances, only one id is every getting sent when i need it to have different ids. I need to have multiple clients running each with their own unique id.
Hope that made sense

Just start VS again.  At least once for the client and again for the server project.

Right-click project -> Debug -> start new instance.

Please show code details. You can use process id.

I think I have this issue sorted but thank you Minxin

I can think of two options to achieve that:
Option 1: "Just Run it" approach

Build your GUI project
Find the executables (bin\Debug or bin\Release)
Launch as many instances as you like
(Optional) You can attach the debugger in VS. Debug -> Attach to Process... and pick the specific app instance you want to peek into.

Option 2: Multiple projects approach

Clone the GUI project to multiple projects in VS
Setup Multiple projects to debug: Right-click your solution in Visual Studio, go to "Set Startup Projects...", choose "Multiple Startup Projects," and tell it to start both your cloned clients GUI projects and server project.

Option 1 gives you more freedom but you can debug only one project at once, option 2 is more complicated but you can debug all instances of your GUI projects.

I would suggest combination of the two - set multiple startup projects to client and server, and any additional GUI apps should be run from built executable.

Please see my updates question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

When you execute two or more clients, do the second client sends the ID, or only the first client is able to send data over to server?

Both clients send their data, however the server ive made only receives the first client's data and not the second's, despite them both being sent. This is a separate issue to my initial post

Ok, I suggest you create another question with all this information on stackoverflow, describe the API of your server (rest API, TCP socket or any other), share the part of the client code where the connection with the server is established . Debugging the client that does not connect to the server, any exception error is generated?
Share all this information and then add a link to that question here. :)
